# response.redirect is not waiting for the redirection to complete

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a small redirection code which redirects the current request to a jsp page and has to wait till the jsp page executes and then resume execution of the main thread which is to load a congratulations page for the user.

My code looks like below:

```
private void PostToCallBackPage(String url, String postdata)
{
try
{
    log.Debug(url + "?" + postdata);
    Response.Redirect(url + "?" + postdata);   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Error("PostToCallBackPage error: " + ex.Message);
}
log.Debug("end of PostToCallBackPage");
Response.Redirect(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CongratulationPage"] + QueryString);
}
```

However i don't see the redirection to the congratulations happening. I see clientabortexception in the logs. Can i get help on seeing what i'm doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Once you've redirected, you can't redirect the same request again. That's just now how the web works. That single HTTP request is over.

Answer (score 1):

> which redirects the current request to a jsp page and has to wait till the jsp page executes

nope; that's not going to happen. From the server's perspective, a redirect is the *end* of a request - it involves sending a 301/302/307/whatever response for the current request, along with a new url - and *that's it*. The server cannot wait - that concept literally doesn't exist. Http (1.* at least) is a request-response protocol; the client made one request - the server sends one response. Once the server-side code signals that it wants to redirect, then from the server's perspective: *that's it* - there's nothing more to do.

Comment: Marc doesn't Response.Redirect(url + "?" + postdata,false); help?

Comment: @user2562884 Did you try it to see if it helped? What about that leads you to believe that it's going to somehow change how HTTP requests/responses work?

Comment: @user2562884 no, that makes no difference whatsoever